# What is an idiom for overcoming a life obstacle?

Tags: phrases, expressions, idioms, phrase-requests, idiom-requests

It's on the tip of my tongue -- something related to a tool like "to pass through a vise". The meaning is along the lines of overcoming a character-defining struggle in your life; the kind a person only goes through once a lifetime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know whether characters can be said to pass through a vise, exactly. *Gripped* maybe the more likely expression concerning vises, unless you want to invoke the idea of escape.  But if other tools are in scope, how about *forged in the crucible of X*, where x is your momentous struggle?  Anvils and furnaces are other instances where forging happens and mettle is proved, but I am too ignorant of smithery to say whether they are good tool metaphors.

Answer (score 1):

**Rise above** — [TFD](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Rise+Above)

> 2. *Fig.* [for one] to ignore petty matters and do what one is meant to do in spite of them.
>      *"He was able to rise above the squabbling and bring some sense to the proceedings."*

Comment: Always include the relevant definition, and a good example sentence. Hope my edit shows you how to do it. :)

Comment: @NVZ Got it. I will next time.